# How to fix 'unable to import gurobipy', undefined variable 'model', and undefined variable 'GRB' in VSCode & Python?

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code, path, gurobi

I am trying to write an optimization code for the seating layout of a Boeing 777x using Gurobi in python, and am encountering error messages with my code. Specifically, pylint errors with importing gurobipy (pylint(import-error)), undefined variable 'Model' (pylint(undefined-variable)), and undefined variable 'GRB' (pylint(undefined-variable)).

I am rather new to coding and am unsure if gurobipy or pylint is possibly downloaded into the wrong place and cannot be accessed by VSCode. I have gurobi.lic, gurobi.log, the pylint folder, and my code (BoeingOptimization.py) all saved into the same folder on my desktop. Those same files (folder in the case of pylint) are also somewhere else in the user files too. I think there may be some sort of path issue because I believe everything is downloaded, but possibly in the wrong locations?

```
# !/usr/bin/python
from gurobipy import *

# Create the model to be used in the terminal
m = Model("777x Optimization")

# Name and Create the variables
x1 = m.addVar(name="First-Class Seat Pitch [in]")
x2 = m.addVar(name="First-Class Seat Width [in]")
x3 = m.addVar(name="First-Class Seat Thickness [in]")
x4 = m.addVar(name="Premium-Economy Seat Pitch [in]")
x5 = m.addVar(name="Premium-Economy Seat Width [in]")
x6 = m.addVar(name="Premium-Economy Seat Thickness [in]")
x7 = m.addVar(name="Number of First-Class Rows")
x8 = m.addVar(name="Number of Premium-Economy Rows")
x9 = m.addVar(name="Number of First-Class Seats Per Row")
x10 = m.addVar(name="Number of Premium-Economy Seats per Row")

# Set objective: f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8)
obj = x7*x9*(x1+x2+x3) + x8*x10*(x4+x5+x6)
m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Add constraints
m.addConstr((x7*x1*x2)+(x4*x5*x8) <= 342625, "Area Constraint")
m.addConstr(1512*x8 + 5410*x7 >= 202182, "Ticket Revenue             Constraint")
m.addConstr(0.25*x5 + 0.35*x6 +0.4*x4 >= 18.6975, "Premium-Economy    Comfort Level Constraint")
m.addConstr(0.25*x2 + 0.35*x3 +0.4*x1 >= 29.16, "First-Class Economy Comfort Constraint")
m.addConstr(x8 - 1.4*x7 >= 0 , "Ratio of First Class to Economy Class Seats Constraint")
m.addConstr(x1 >= 57, "Minimum First-Class Pitch Constraint")
m.addConstr(x2 >= 25, "Minimum First-Class Width Constraint")
m.addConstr(x3 >= 3, "Minimum First-Class Thickness Constraint")
m.addConstr(x4 >= 36, "Minimum Premium-Economy Pitch Constraint")
m.addConstr(x5 >= 18.5, "Minimum Premium-Economy Width Constraint")
m.addConstr(x6 >= 1.5, "Minimum Premium-Economy Thickness Constraint")
m.addConstr(x9*x2 <= 233.04, "Seats Per Aisle Constraint First-Class")
m.addConstr(x10*x5 <= 233.04, "Seats Per Aisle Constraint Premium-Economy")
m.optimize()

for v in m.getVars():
    print('%s %g' % (v.varName, v.x))

print('Obj: %g' % obj.getValue())
```

Comment: Have you checked that the Python interpreter (in the bottom left of VS Code) is what you expect - same version and directory?

Comment: This was the correct fix. VSCode was using Python 3.7 but gurobi was installed for Python 2.7.15. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As an extra tip, explicitly import what you're going to use and don't use `import *`. It can confuse tools (and yourself). Plus it's frowned upon when done outside of the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to select the correct Python interpreter to be used by VSCode (selectable from the bottom left corner of VSCode - check that it is the same version and directory that you expect).